# How can I add chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html to manifest in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension,
I run a content script on the activeTab and it works just fine on other tabs, but when I run the script on a new tab, the browser throws an error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host."
I thought I could add this url to the manifest file, but it doesn't work. I have seen some solutions for other problems on stackoverflow, but none of them worked so far.

This is how I execute script:

```
var link = 'http://localhost/example/abc.html';
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'currentWindow': true}, function (tabs) {

            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {
                    file: "lib/prefetch.js"
                  }, function() {
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {link: link});
                    resolve(0);//resolve the promise

            });

        });
```

Manifest.json is as the following:

```
{
  "name": "Example Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Example extension",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/grey-16.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", 
    "notifications",
    "background", 
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "contentSettings",
    "browsingData",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts" : [
   {
     "js": [ "index.js", "ext/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"],
     "matches": ["*://*/*"]
   },
   {
     "js": [ "content.js", "onexecute.js"],
     "run_at": "document_start",
     "matches": ["*://*/*"]
   }
  ],
  "background": {
      "scripts" : ["ext/jquery-2.1.4.min.js","ext/async.min.js","ext/himalaya.js","background.js"],
      "persistent": true,
      "matches": ["*://*/*"]
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://rawgit.com/caolan/async/master/dist/async.min.js https://ajax.googleapis.com;  object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: I saw this thanks, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the manifest file? That's what the error tells you update.

Comment: I added the manifest file

Comment: Content script can't run on the default built-in new tab page.

Comment: But I try to run it after the new url is put to the address bar and it is executed on the "headersRecevied" event. Is it still applied in this case?

Comment: I tried to change the new tab with "chrome_url_overrides" but the same error thrown : "extension://knp....fdjb/page.html". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host"

Comment: I am experiencing a very similar problem Did you have any luck with this one?

Comment: unfortunately no, I don't really remember but I think I ended up creating the new tab with "about:blank" URL. You might want to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I also cannot run this on a new tab.  I have these permissions:

```
"permissions": [
  "contextMenus",
  "tabs",
  "activeTab",
  "https://*/",
  "notifications",
  "<all_urls>",
  "storage"
],
```

I think a new tab doesn't have a url set so you won't be able to run from a new tab.